# How to put breaks in string fetching from database to view on FPDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

I am printing the contents of MySql table on PDF using FPDF.
I have a column for text where usually long strings are input. When i am printing this on FPDF using Cell function the whole string is exceeding the cell it should be in.
I want that whole string should be made visible in one single cell by putting breaks in the string and also expanding the height of the cell automatically according to number of lines printed.

Following is the relevant part of my PHP code. I am also attaching a screenshot of generated PDF to give better idea.

[image: Issue Column Contents exceeding their designated cell.]

```
    $module = $_POST['module'];
$client = $_POST['client'];
$severity = $_POST['severity'];
$issue = $_POST['issue'];
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
mysql_select_db($database);
$res = mysql_query("select * from parent");

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", "20");
$pdf->Cell(187,15, "Detailed Bugs Report",1,0,C);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont("Times","B","15");

        $pdf->Cell(48,10, "MODULE",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(22,10, "CLIENT",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, "SEVERITY",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(27,10, "DATE",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(60,10, "ISSUE",1,0,C);
        $pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","","12");
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    $pdf->Cell(48,10, "$row[0]",1,0); 
    $pdf->Cell(22,10, "$row[1]",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, "$row[2]",1,0,C); 
    $pdf->Cell(27,10, "$row[3]",1,0,C);
        //$cellWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($row[4]);
        $pdf->Cell(60, 10, $row[4], 1, 0); 
        $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MultiCell](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm) instead of Cell to put your text in. It should add a line break at the end of the cell and wrap the text automatically or you can use \n as a line break to explicitly wrap the text.

Comment: Ok I used Multicell instead of Cell for last cell. It shows some improvement but not exactly what i wanted. I have to show it to you. I am afraid i can not attach pictures to comments. I am adding a new answer with screenshot of PDF. Please see to it and suggest what can be done further?

Comment: it looks like it is using justification (default value) as alignment. So you could try it like this: `$pdf->MultiCell(60, 10, $row[4], 1, 'L');` this would change alignment to left.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there spaces before initial words and more than usual spaces. it is still somewhat exceeding the boundary of cell.
[image: Still exceeding the cell boundary]